# How to control the header's title of index obtained from pandas df.reset_index() twice

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, indexing

I do `df.reset_index()` twice in my code. The first reset gives me the new column with 'index' as a title in the header. Can I change this?

```
aaa = df.reset_index().melt(['prot', iso_head,'index'], mz_header)

           prot    isoab0  index   variable       value
39   ALBU_HUMAN  0.508396     39  [M+2H+]2+  593.284410
669  ALBU_HUMAN  0.508396     39  [M+3H+]3+  395.858700
670  ALBU_HUMAN  0.504033     40  [M+3H+]3+  399.201120
```

Because when I do `df.reset_index()` the second round (after `.dropna()`), the real index at the first column is changed to be in `'level_0'` column. The 'index' column remains like above. And the new reset index column is at the first column. This is very confusing. Why this time the `.reset_index()` doesn't gives me the new column with title 'index' like the first round? What is a good way to manage many index column? Is it good to drop some of them?

```
aaa = aaa.dropna().sort_values('index')
aaa = aaa.reset_index()

    level_0        prot    isoab0  index   variable       value
50       39  ALBU_HUMAN  0.508396     39  [M+2H+]2+  593.284410
51      669  ALBU_HUMAN  0.508396     39  [M+3H+]3+  395.858700
52      670  ALBU_HUMAN  0.504033     40  [M+3H+]3+  399.201120
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because you already have a column named index, you can use rename_axis before reindexing if you want an alternative name i.e

```
df.rename_axis('INDEX').reset_index()
```

Also set the index name using .name i.e (Thanks @coldspeed) :

```
df.index.name = 'INDEX'
df.reset_index()

   INDEX        prot    isoab0  index   variable      value
0     39  ALBU_HUMAN  0.508396     39  [M+2H+]2+  593.28441
1    669  ALBU_HUMAN  0.508396     39  [M+3H+]3+  395.85870
2    670  ALBU_HUMAN  0.504033     40  [M+3H+]3+  399.20112
```

Comment: Nicely done. You've beaten me by a few seconds. May as well also add in that you can set `df.index.name = ...`